# How to best implement recyclerviews inside a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to implement a business logic where each day of the week will be represented by the child elements of a viewpager. However, each element will contain a recyclerview that will query a DB and each of the query will be slightly different depending on the viewpager child selected. What is the best way to implement it? I could go with creating 7 fragments but that seems rather wasteful. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to my understanding of your question. If your every weekday has same fields of data than you can make a single fragment and if they have different data fields than you should go for 7 fragments. Hope this will help you.
It will be better if you share the data of the query. Thank you.

Comment: It's the exact same data and there is only 1 viewType in the recyclerview. I am using Firestore and the day of the week corresponding to the document is saved in an array. So I just use the "whereArrayContains" to get the info. So if Mon and Wed are present then I show of the document data in the Monday and Wednesday recyclerviews. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: My recommendation is to use just one fragment with recycler view. Hope that will help.
If you want more clarify answer post your code etc.